# Kiel traduki la anglan esprimon "Pull yourself together"?

Tags: translation, idiom

"*Pull yourself together*" estas angla esprimo, kiu signifas ke la parolanto volas ke sia aŭdanto ĉesu panikiĝi, trankviliĝu, kuraĝu kaj agu prudente.

Ĉu ekzistas simila esprimo en esperanto?

Comment: `Rekolektu vin` estus iomgrade internacia idiomaĵo/metaforo (en+de+fr+nl), mi pensas.

Answer (score 3):

Ekregu vin! Reakiru la memregadon! Reprenu la sinregadon!

Ekzemploj el Tekstaro:

> Ekregu vin, sinjoro, kiel konvenas al venka militestro...
>
> li iom trankviliĝis kaj reakiris la sinregadon

Comment: Dankon! Mi neniam antaŭe legis aŭ audis la esprimon, "ekregu vin!" kaj ĝi bone taŭgos por mia tradukado. Ĝi estas konvene abrupta.